# Discord 14 OpenAI integration

Tags: node.js, api, discord, request, openai-api

I'm trying to integrate OpenAI to Discord bot, but for some reason, I'm not able to get the response from the ChatGPT. I'm not sure where the issue is.

1. I have confirmed that the API key is correct
2. I have confirmed that org ID is also correct
3. I have confirmed that the prompt from the user interaction is returned correctly
4. I have 18$ trial balance from the OpenAI API till 1st June and 0$ was spent.

```
//ChatGPT Config
const { Configuration, OpenAI Api } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "org-MyORGID",
    apiKey: process.env.GPT_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
    //discord interaction
    async execute(interaction) {
        try {
        console.log(process.env.GPT_KEY); //confirm Api KEY and print to the console
        const prompt = interaction.options.getString('prompt'); //Get prompt from user
        console.log(prompt); //Log prompt from user
        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            prompt: prompt,
            maxTokens: 1000,
            n: 1,
            stop: ['\n']
        });
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: false });
        await wait(6000);
        const message = response.choices[0].text.trim();
        console.log(message); //should log the message generated by GPT 
        await interaction.editReply({ content: `This is what you said: ${prompt} \n\nChatGPT: ${message}`});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: false });
        await interaction.editReply({ content: `Error: Open AI API is not responding right now and we can't do anything about it. \nPlease try again later`});
      }
    }
};
```

Error:

```
0|Bot  | Error: Request failed with status code 400
0|Bot  |     at createError (/dev/Bot/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
```

Likey I think there is some problem with this code, but I'm not sure what's wrong. I want to use this model **gpt-3.5-turbo $0.002 / 1K tokens**.

Likely the problem:

```
        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            prompt: prompt,
            maxTokens: 1000,
            n: 1,
            stop: ['\n']
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following, the supported model for GPT 3.5 is for example `text-davinci-002` and not `gpt-3.5-turbo`.

You can browse all working models through this link https://api.openai.com/v1/engines

You need to login to the link provided above just with the password (password is your API Key generated on https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys) with blank username (so leave username empty).

Working Code:

```
        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: 'text-davinci-002',
            prompt: prompt,
            maxTokens: 1000,
        });
```